# WPF input type/dialog box?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to take a single input from the user and delete some information form the grid which i display. So for this i want to raise a input box/dialog box which accepts the text and when i hit the button on the dialog box,i want to save the data.

Is it possible with out creating a new window or usercontrol ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF C# InputBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103743/wpf-c-sharp-inputbox)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean something like VB 6 `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox` there is nothing out of the box for both WinForms and WPF.

But of course many people coming from Delphi and VB6 are missing this you can find a lot of ready solutions in the Internet, for instance: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/InputBox.aspx

Comment: You can use the VB one itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1456550/3195477

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge there is no built-in dialogue for input (aside from `MessageBox`). You could create a window on the fly though if you do not want to subclass it. Just create a new window instance in code and set its `Content` to have some default `Buttons` (OK & Cancel) and a `TextBox`.