# Displaying modal dialogs using PRISM 4

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, prism-4

I'm developing a .NET 4.0 application using PRISM and MVVM, as well as WPF.

I currently have a shell subdivided in regions, with views inserted in them. When the user clicks on a button in one of the views, I would like a custom-made modal dialog to be displayed on top of all the views, but still within the same shell.

I looked at the StockTrader RI example and their implementation of the RegionPopupBehavior. Basically, they created a dependency property which allows them to define regions with a specific, custom-made behavior. The behavior is the one in charge of handling it's associated view's rendering, hence displaying it as a popup window.

The only downside to this approach is that all the other views are still active, so the popup isn't modal. I guess this can be resolved by manually disabling all un-needed regions in the shell, but I'm not sure how "clean" this is.

I was wondering if there were a better and simpler approach to displaying modal pop-up views in Prism ?

Comment: This is WPF, not Silverlight, right?

Comment: Maybe you could use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103743/wpf-c-sharp-inputbox/8103869#8103869 ? I use this with a modified version for MVVM to do the same thing.

Comment: You might be interested in a custom [PopupUserControl](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) I have posted on my blog that behaves like that

Comment: @Rachel: This is exactly what I needed, thank you. I plan on binding the popup's content to a UserControl, I guess this will also work ? (Instead of using DataTemplates).

Comment: @HusseinKhalil I posted that as an answer, along with a few examples of how to set the `Content` of the popup. You can bind the `Content` property to a `UserControl`, although if you're using the MVVM design pattern then your ViewModels really shouldn't have any UI objects in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in a custom [PopupUserControl](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) I have posted on my blog that behaves like that.

Usually I use it like this:

```
<local:PopupPanel 
    Content="{Binding PopupContent}"
    local:PopupPanel.PopupParent="{Binding ElementName=SomeParentPanel}"
    local:PopupPanel.IsPopupVisible="{Binding IsPopupVisible}">

    <local:PopupPanel.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeViewModel}">
            <local:SomeView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DifferentViewModel}">
            <local:DifferentView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:PopupPanel.Resources>

</local:PopupPanel>
```

Although you can also just write the Content in the popup instead of binding the Content property

```
<local:PopupPanel 
    local:PopupPanel.PopupParent="{Binding ElementName=SomeParentPanel}"
    local:PopupPanel.IsPopupVisible="{Binding IsPopupVisible}">

    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2">
        <local:MyUserControl />
    </Border>
</local:PopupPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you ! You are right about the fact that a ViewModel shouldn't have any UI element in it. I guess the best solution is as you suggested: bind to an object and have data templates...