# Graphical Failure with InputBox and MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

In my WPF-project im popping up an Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox to get a filename from the user. If this filename is already in use im popping up a System.Windows.MessageBox to show the hint, that its already in use. After i hit OK on the MessageBox and it closed, i still see parts of the InputBox mixed up with some elements(a button) from my main programm.
Why does this happen?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't want to use any Windows.Forms based controls in a WPF application, it's just somehow against the point. You can easily create your own input box though, with the advantage of total control over behavior and style. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103743/wpf-c-sharp-inputbox) stackoverflow describes your problem very nicely.

Comment: Is there no way of configuring my programm to work without programming an inputdialog myself?

Comment: Well, your program DOES work, it just causes some gfx glitches. However, I'm not experienced enough in the combined use of WinForms + WPF to tell you whether there is a solution. AFAIK, it's best to use either one of them and stick with that decision. The complete workflow of a WPF application is very different to a classical WinForms application, including draw calls, and I'd suggest this is whats causing your gfx glitches. In my opinion, there is no other way as to write an input box yourself. Just look at it as a new possibility to learn something.