# Is there a way to implement a tooltip-esque confirmation dialog on a button in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, dialog, popup

I'm looking to create a confirmation dialog on a delete button in my WPF program. Just using a regular dialogbox would work, but I'd like to style it to look and in some ways act like a tooltip.

[image: This is the idea]

Comment: You could probably use a [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview).

Comment: 1) take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103743/wpf-c-sharp-inputbox 2) try 3rd party components

Comment: @redcurry Popup could be not "user friendly" -- for example: auto close on lose focus

Comment: @Zam Can't that behavior be customized with the `IsOpen` and `StaysOpen` properties?

Comment: @redcurry The issues I've noticed with popup are that it stays in the same spot when moving the window. Which I guess isn't too big of a deal because they shouldn't be moving the window after hitting delete anyways. I'll play around with it and see if run into any other problems.

Comment: @Zam Maybe I'm just not thinking hard enough, but would there be a way to transition between visible and collapsed without disturbing the locations of other controls on the screen. I'd like for it to just appear and cover other items without changing the layout by taking the space other controls occupy